# How to construct instance of class using json object array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying construct the class's object from the array.

```
import searchData from '../somepath/data.json';
```

And the data.json file have the following data.

```
[
  {
    "name": "London"
  },
  {
    "name": "Paris",
  }
]
```

Then I'm looping it using the forEach.

```
searchData.forEach((obj: OneClass) => {
});
```

Here is the class

```
export class OneClass{
  readonly name: string;
}
```

It is not working well, I'm getting some kind of type error.

But when I just change the type of searchData to any then it works perfectly,

```
const searchData: any = [
    {
        'name': 'a'
    }, 
    {
        'name': 'b'
    }, 
    ];
```

**Note:** some code are missing due to privacy restriction, so just trying to understand how the construct the object of typescript class using array objects.

**Edited:**

The json data was importing using the following method.

```
import searchData from '../somepath/data.json';
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: @ThomasSablik the code was too complex and large, that's why I tried to make it short. You can say the searchData is importing from the json file. I have updated my question.

Comment: Why is it readonly ? Are you trying to cast from JSON ?

Comment: @Pogrindis not sure about that, not familiar with Typescript just trying to understand the code of one project. -_- I have the basic knowledge of javascript but not the advanced, that's why struggling.

Comment: Use an `interface`, not a `class`, if you don't have any methods and no prototype inheritance but only plain data.

Comment: Yes, as above, interface will allow to `import as`. or `const arrDeser: Interface = <Interface[]>json;`

Comment: @Bergi does that affect the construction of the instance? I just want to confirm why I have to mention the type `any` on the searchData constant.

Comment: Ali,  once your data is in the same struct as your interface, and you're not using any polymorphism/methods, theres no need for a class.

Comment: @MuhammadAli Well, yes, an interface has no constructor. It doesn't even exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can either annotate your array explicitly ..

```
// tell TS that the variable holds an array of objects 
// shaped like instances of OneClass
const searchData: OneClass[] = [
  {
    name: 'a'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'b'
  }, 
];
```

or use a so-called [const assertion](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/const-assertions-in-literal-expressions-in-typescript).

```
const myConstArr = [
    {
      name: 'bar'
    } as const 
    // the `as const` tells TS that the value of `name` is not going to change 
    // (that it is a "string literal type" and not just of type `string`)
]
```

Have a look at the concept of [Type Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=3&pln=21&pc=1#code/AQYwNghgzlwPIDsCmBhSNgG8BQxgCckIATAewTAE9gEIBbJALmCgBd8BLBAcwG5tcocm3wBXEK1L4AFLQbMRXbgEosgvKwAWHKADo5SYAF4a9JIIC%202K9gBmohBI7lgYUtzTQoSKNPBefZkRUdCgAbQBdVRw8fxgfXVspAFEIEE0-YVIwJF03FWsBEGFWYDpKAEF8fCDkTxhI42AwwRi8U3lgAHIk0i7LbAiBfPrvX3Kq-FUAemngUgBrIpKyyhQSyaaW9rUdvANmLoAjCHx%20nYtgaCEENkHgYfdRn2ly9dvWSZm5xaA) for you to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing is trying to create an instance of the class for each item in your array of objects, you need to map and call the constructor:

```js
interface SearchDatum {
 name: string;
}

const searchData: SearchDatum[] = [
  {
    'name': 'a'
  }, 
  {
    'name': 'b'
  }, 
];

class OneClass {
  readonly name: string;

  constructor({ name }: SearchDatum) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const classInstances: OneClass[] = searchData.map((datum) => new OneClass(datum));
```

[Here is a Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTlBALAInMAVwFtkBvAKGRDmIgC5kBnMKUAcwG4KBfCihAHsQLZhix4CcRukw58RYgG0AusgC8yJVXI7kyAOQ06BxgbgGdPADTIdlffqO0IpwwCNL+m3ZXcBADZwTEzIAPIgEADCQSG6+lAYACbCAQCe1C6MLGwgXPz6QiKshAhgglAAFGSZdMg8MuLyBCQAlPGOYNjATAB0xiiaA9zevPxFogixTACSxXAgSEyMEdHTqhpicpJgcL3EcAAOlZXAkMTt6gB81BAA7uGRMcFMp+etrf4TggEQvQGCdiVKYvOYsBZLT5AA)

Comment: What is a JSON array?

Comment: Also defined a Type outside the method, `{ name: string}` encourages bad practice with TS>

Comment: added explicit type

Answer (score 0):

You should type your array

```
const searchData: OneClass[] = [
{
    'name': 'a'
}, 
{
    'name': 'b'
}, 
];
```

Comment: I might be crazy, but if `OneClass` has `name` defined, you sure you need `'`s? - to me the `{}` parentheses smells like somone using `any` or  `{ }`..

Comment: @Pogrindis Quotes or apostrophes are optional around property names, they are only required for things that are no identifiers. Has nothing to do with interface declarations.

Comment: Nice to know. Everydays a schoolday

Comment: Why I have to mention the data type OneClass? `any` will not be enough? Or during the forEach it shouldn't automatically be casting of {} to the object?

Comment: @MuhammadAli You should never use `any`. The whole concept of TypeScript is to type your variables. Don't use `any`. You should even disallow it in your configuration.